# How to select a specific node programmatically?

Tags: jstree

I have a jstree. I want to select the node which is bound to the object which has a location with id of 158. This works but seems stupid. What's the more idiomatic way of doing this?

```
var $tree = $('.jstree', myContext),
    node = $tree.find('li').filter(function() { 
        return ( $(this).data().location || {}).id === 158;
    });
$tree.jstree('select_node', n)
```

Comment: The above code doesn't work for you? Could you provide jsfidlle sample?

Comment: @Radek - it works, but it seems like there has got to be a better way of doing this than 'grab all li and test their data'. It feels like I can't find the front door and am using a side one. This for example could break if there are changes to the tree structure while it is filtering or if list items are added/removed manually.

Comment: I have the same problem, but every solution I find out there assumes that I have some mysterious "ID" to select. But I don't. I just have a recursive JSON dict/array and no IDs. Is there no way to select a node just by path, such as /path/to/some/file?

Answer (score 46):

Just wanted to chime in here as none of the answers worked for me.  What finally DID work was very simple:

`$('#someTree').jstree('select_node', 'someNodeId');`

Note that I didn't initialize `someNodeId` as a jQuery object.  It's just a plain string.

I did this right after a tree was loaded *without* putting it into a "ready" bind event as it seems to not be necessary.

Hope it saves some one from a few frustrating hours. . .

To hook into the tree after it has been loaded:

```
.on('loaded.jstree', function() {
    // Do something here...
  });
```

Comment: The loaded.jstree part helped me.

Comment: It works, but I'm not a fan of string based method invocation. I prefer $("#someTree").jstree().select_node(["nodeId1", "nodeId2"]) syntax.

Comment: @shantaram--Great, glad it helped you. Gotta love stackoverflow!

Comment: @MattCashatt I have a question, how can i create an object of `someNodeId` in $('#someTree').jstree('select_node', 'someNodeId');. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666785/jstree-how-to-send-array-to-select-node-method) i post a question about it.

Answer (score 23):

Based on [jsTree groups](http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/8b9113f4743bab21) you can try

```
jQuery("#getStartedTree").jstree("select_node", "#test2");
```

if the data looks like

```
The JSON in the TextFile.txt - borrowed from your simple example
 [
     {
     "data" : "A node",
     "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]
     },
     {
     "attr" : { "id" : "test1" },
         "data" : {
             "title" : "Long format demo",
             "attr" : { "id" : "test2", "href" : "#" }
         }
     }
 ]
```

and jsTree set up

```
My tree container is <div id="getStartedTree">

My jsTree code
 $("#getStartedTree").jstree({
            "themes": {
                "theme": "default",
                "url": "../App_Css/Themes/Default/style.css",
                "dots": true,
                "icons": true
            },
            "json_data": {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "../SiteMaps/TextFile.txt",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "data": function(n) {
                        return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui"]
        });
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: But here you have to assign ids to nodes as you create them and somehow figure out the correlating id. I don't know how they implemented it but the API I'm looking for would be something like get_node_bound_to. `var treeData = $jstree.jstree('data'), nodeData = findCorrectNodeIn(data); node = $jstree.jstree('get_node_bound_to', nodeData); $jstree.jstree('select_node', node);`

Comment: When do you assign id to your node? And how?

Comment: I would be really really shocked if they didn't provide a way to do this. The li technique doesn't really work that great. For example I need to select a node for data matching certain criteria when the dialog containing the jstree opens. Using this li hack I have to listen to the loaded event and only then do the selection.

Comment: Currently, this is all based on dynamic data and the control was written by another developer who did not generate ids. But there really seems to be no reason to use them. I know the criteria for the data node I want and those data nodes are the jstree's model. Indeed, if I pulled up multiple side-by-side copies of the same jstree, using ids would explicitly fail.

Comment: If you don't have id's you have to do some kind of search, do you.

Comment: Yes, I do a search through the data model - see the filter block in my original question or the findCorreectNodeIn function above. This returns the node in the data model that the node in the UI that I want is bound to. I mean this _has_ to be a very common operation. Creating a button to expand all nodes containing a certain text for example.

Comment: But in your search above you use some kind of id (.id === 158;)

Comment: That is a coincidence. The javascript object that is being bound (it is apparently stored in data-location for each li) has an id property. The DOM elements themselves have no ids

Comment: So hoe do you know then what to select?

Comment: Well look at my "working but shitty" code - it works by looking through the data that jstree attaches to each list item. That is another thing I'm worrid about - that's not a guaranteed interface.

Comment: If the id is a coincidence how else do you want to to the search?

Comment: I'm not sure what the confusion can be. jstree seems to use a standard view-model pattern. The vm in this case is the hierarchy of data-bound object nodes. If I can identify a node then there is a jstree node that correlates to it. The filter function above simply identifies a node. This has nothing to do with the HTML id attribute.

Comment: I don't understand. How come it has nothing to do with id if you use a `condition === 158` ?

Comment: Radek, the id in `<div id="thisdiv"></div>` is an xml attribute named id. The id property of an object `{id: 123}` is just a property on an object that happens to be named 'id'. They are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Can you add id to nodes when creating data?

Comment: Not easily, but adding id nodes at the time I create the data will be almost as fragile as my current approach. My question is what is the "correct" way of handling this requirement. Lots of people use jstree and this is not such a crazy thing that I'm trying to do so I would imagine there is something less hacky that I just don't know about.

Comment: I am still lost :-) Why is that fragile? If you want to select a node you have to identify the node. Somehow. Why not by using id?

Comment: 1) Because ids are supposed to be unique to the page - so what if you want 2 copies of the same tree, 2) because you have to invent an algorithm for generating ids, 3) because someone might add a node to the jstree without knowing that they're supposed to assign an id to it 4) because between the time when you create an id and when you try to find by it, the data that UI node is bound to might have changed. Basically I want to go from data bound object directly to the bound node. Introducing an id is introducing yet another concept and another possible point of failure.

Comment: The ONLY reason why DOM ids are not exactly as fragile as the approach I outlined is because it does not depend on the undocumented presence of the viewmodel node in the UI node's data() object

Answer (score 6):

I did it with:

```
$('.jstree').jstree(true).select_node('element id');
```

this code:

```
jQuery.each(produto.categorias, function(i, categoria) {
    $('#lista-categorias').jstree(true).select_node(categoria.dadoCategoria.id);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to deselect first. I did it with $('#f_tree').jstree(true).deselect_all(true);

Answer (score 5):

I was able to simulate a click on a jstree node as an alternative way to select a node.
The following code is what was used :

```
$(treeIdHandle + " li[id=" + nodeId + "] a").click();
```

Comment: This would require each node to have an id attribute which is one of the things that is not available by default (and would be terrible for performance if it was). However, in your case where the id exists, it should be possible to simplify to `$('a', '#'+nodeId).click()`

Comment: Yes, it would require each node to have an id attribute or even any other attribute which can uniquely identify a node in a tree.

Answer (score 3):

If you're populating the tree using HTML instead of JSON data and wondering how to set the `node_id`, you just need to set the id attribute of the `<li>` element!

```html
<div class="tree-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="node_1">
            Node 1 - Level 1
           <ul class="menu">
               <li id="node_3">
                   Node 3 - Level 2
               </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="node_2">
            Node 2 - Level 1
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then

```js
$('.tree-menu')
    .jstree(true)
    .select_node("node_3");
```

will select the `Node 3 - Level 2` node.

For **those getting javascript errors**, remember to use Full version of `jQuery`, not the slim version!

For all **down voters**, here is the demo to prove it's working:
https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/75v3fLbs/7/

[image]

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: [...] .jstree(...).select_node is not a function`

Comment: See my updates... Please no down vote just because you're getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

i use jstree 3.0.8.  don't use 'state'

```
'plugins' : ['dnd','sort','types','contextmenu','wholerow','ui']
```

and server offer the json, the selected node has

```
"state":{"selected":true,"opened":true}
```

Comment: This sounds promising but can you please provide a better example or some documentation? This is not enough for someone starting out with jstree to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This solution Works for me

```
// after the tree is loaded
$(".jstree").on("loaded.jstree", function(){
    // don't use "#" for ID
    $('.jstree').jstree(true).select_node('ElementId');
});
```

and even in a php loop (dynamically) :

```
$(".jstree").on("loaded.jstree", function(){
    <?php foreach($tree as $node): ?>
        $('.jstree').jstree(true).select_node('<?=$node?>');
    <?php endforeach;?>
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It is asking how to select a node that is bound to a given object - NOT the dom element. If you read the comments on the top answer, this is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

i think u should write code to select node after jstree initialized, therefore use this code

```
 $('#jstree')
    .on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
       // do function after jstree initialized
      $('#jstree')
        .jstree(true)
        .select_node('nodeid');
    });
```

hope its work :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't really an answer to the question. The question is not about using nodeid, its about how to select by an arbitrary property of the object that the node was generated from.

Answer (score -1):

trigger click on first anchor

```
$("#jstree .jstree-anchor:first").click();
```

or by node id *158*

```
$("#jstree #158").find(".jstree-anchor:first").click(); 

$('#' + 158).find(".jstree-anchor:first").click();
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question asked