# Programmatically select checkboxes in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a jstree with the checkboxes plugin enabled and need to select some checkboxes dependant on ids. The checkboxes have names such as name_1, name_23 etc so the number is just the id of the element.

What I am doing is looping the array and then just setting the check box to checked

```
  for (var c = 0; c < cams.length; c++) {
      $("#check_" + cams[c]).prop('checked', true);
  }
```

however the checkboxes are not checked in the ui, but if I expand the node the checkboxes that were selected for that parent and child are shown selected.

However if I am trying to select a checkbox on a child node it does not show at all even after expanding the parent node. (the parent node shows a selected square though to indicate a child is selected)

I am using "progressive_render: true" so could this be causing the child parent issue.

Am I doing this the correct way, or is there an easier way?

It seems like it would be a common thing to do so I would have though that there alt to be a load method.

Cheers
Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select a specific node programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466370/how-to-select-a-specific-node-programmatically)

Comment: had a look and this is not my issue